# Sort DateTime object in DD/MM/YYYY format in .cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, razor

I currently have a for-loop in my .cshtml file which iterates through items inside  a ViewBag. I want to sort these objects based on a DateTime property called orderDate in the Order.cs file. The for loop in the .cshtml file looks like the following:

```
<table id="order-history-table" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Order Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Order Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Order Total
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.list)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="orderNumber" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-container" href="@Url.Action("orderDetails", "Orders", new { orderNumber = item.order.OrderNumber })">@item.order.OrderNumber</a>
                <br />
                @Html.ActionLink("Re-Order", "ReOrder", new { orderNumber = @item.order.OrderNumber }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to re-order?');"  })
            </td>
            <td>@item.order.OrderDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">$@(Math.Round(item.order.OrderTotal, 2))</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I want this table to be sorted so that the most recent orders are shown at the top of the table. Since the data is being pulled from a database, and the tables values are generated dynamically, where do I perform this sorting? is it done through jQuery? How do I do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You sort it in the controller (for example using `.OrderByDescending()` in a linq query). And do not use `ViewBag` - pass the model to the view

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) to do that.

So in your action method where you set the ViewBag.list, You can use `OrderByDescending` method on the collection.

```
var yourOrderList=new List<Order>();
// to do : Load Order items to yourOrderList
yourOrderList=yourOrderList.OrderByDescending(f=>f.OrderDate).ToList();
ViewBAg.list=yourOrderList;
```

I also recommend using a view model to pass data from your action method to view.

```
var yourOrderList=new List<Order>();
// to do  : Add orders to yourOrderList
yourOrderList=yourOrderList.OrderByDescending(f=>f.OrderDate).ToList();
return View(yourOrderList);
```

And in your view

```
@model List<Order>
<h3>Orders</h3>
@foreach(var o in Model)
{
  <p>@o.OrderDate.ToString()</p>
}
```

Since your view is strongly typed, you can do the same ordering in your razor view also as needed.

```
@model List<Order>
<h3>Orders</h3>
@foreach(var o in Model.OrderByDescending(g=>g.OrderDate))
{
  <p>@o.OrderDate.ToString()</p>
}
```